# What doctype is considered best practice to use for Wordpress?

Tags: html

I am finding a lot of validation errors courtesy of http://validator.w3.org/ in a clients website with the following HTML tag:

`<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">`

It appears this was also used in the original version of the theme as well. I'm just wondering if I should go for a certain Doctype always over another?

Comment: how is it related to wordpress? This should be asked in an html oriented forum.

Comment: I thought this initially too ,however my logic went along the lines of since I am working with different plugins that often add HTML code that I don't have easy control of - I thought there might be a good way to set a doctype that will work with HTML from different sources, etc.

Comment: doctype is just a hint to the browser how to parse your html. just because you declare your html to be valid in a specific standard doesn't mean it is. This is even a bigger problem with UGC as users always find a way do break HTML in their content.

Answer (score 3):

I think that is currently always a good idea to use the html5 doctype `<!DOCTYPE html>`. The best answer for use this type can you find in this [SE Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14192). The question and answer is not only in the context of WordPress, is always a part of serving on frontend.